# Instance method not found warning, but working

Tags: objective-c, methods, nsmutablearray, warnings

In my implementation model, I need to have some differents files, with some similar methods. Also, I gather objects of differents types in a `NSMutableArray`, and try to call my similar method like this:

```
[[ArrayOfViews objectAtIndex:i] myMethodWithInt:'number' andExample:'char'];
```

But it gives me a warning:

```
Instance method '...' not found (return type defaults to 'id')
```

My code works, but should I fix this warning or not?

Comment: You should always try to fix warnings in C and Objective-C code bases; they generally indicate serious (and often fatal) problems.

Comment: That's why I work hard to detect tand fix them =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should introduce the type:

```
MONType * obj = [ArrayOfViews objectAtIndex:i];
```

Then call the method using the typed variable:

```
[obj myMethodWithInt:<#number#> andExample:<#char#>];
```

It could be complaining for a number of reasons. Introducing the type will either fix those categories of issues, or at least give you a more useful warning. Specifically, **the compiler does not see a declaration of the instance method `-myMethodWithInt:andExample:`**.

You've likely either not imported a header, or declared the method so that it is visible in the translation.

> My code works, but should I must fix this warning or not ?

Maybe. Sometimes it will 'work'. This is equivalent to C89's missing function prototypes, which were phased out because of all the issues they caused. So implicit parameters and return types *can* work if the parameters and return type is `id` compatible (including `NSObject` subclasses). But if it is not a match, then you should expect undefined behavior. You can avoid all this and introduce meaningful type checking by using the appropriate imports and declarations in your programs, and by introducing the type as illustrated above. This is useful because the compiler will save you from a ton of silly mistakes as you work and as your codebases evolve.

Comment: So how could i detect the type of an element of the array ? So the object take the type of the element of the array (which is variable)

Comment: @user2057209 You can use the common base in many cases -- for example, if the array has NSString and NSMutableStrings only, and you need only NSString APIs, you can just use NSString as the common base. otherwise, you would need to use dynamic checking (e.g. `-isKindOfClass:`) which can be 'smelly'. in some cases, introducing a protocol can simplify this process. the logic with the dynamic types in collections is: "you should know what you put into it".

Comment: The elements in the array are all from differents files. So they are all from different classes. The array should get about a hundred elements, so it would be hard to test if `-isKindOfClass:` runs :s You couldn't have a process like [ArrayOfViews objectAtIndex:0] getClass]; (pseudo code) to replace it ?

Comment: @user2057209 illustration of how to structure type introduction: `id obj = [array objectAtIndex:0]; \n if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) { NSArray * array = obj; ...use it... } \n else if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) { NSString * string = obj; ...use it... }`

Comment: Ok i'll try with your solution. Thanks =)

Comment: @user2057209 if they do not have a common base, that may be a good case for using protocols. then you can just declare the variable as `NSObject<SomeProtocol>* obj = [array objectAtIndex:0];` \n safely use obj with `SomeProtocol` methods'.

Comment: @user2057209 but yes, you could map classes to functionalities in many ways in objc -- given the problem posed, it would be atypical to do so in this scenario. the problem (as mentioned in the answer), is that the compiler may not set up the call correctly if the signature differs, which can result in reading and writing to the wrong memory locations (e.g. parameters) which is undefined behavior to read/write that memory. the compiler could see one declaration and assume the signature, but if it sees two with the same selector and different signatures, it deserves intervention/disambiguation.

Comment: I'll try to add some protocols =)

Answer (score 0):

It's probably just a case of not having the method declared before the call. Try adding the method declaration to the interface section of the class.

Comment: Nop, because it's in another file. That's why it's normal to not declare the method in the principal file.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a typecast to your objectAtIndex call with get rid of the warning. This isn't a big issue, but it's good practice to typecast returns from an NSArray.

Basically:

```
YourObjectType *yourObject = (YourObjectType*)[ArrayOfViews objectAtIndex:i];
[yourObject myMethodWithInt:'number' andExample:'char'];
```

Comment: ([[ArrayOfViews objectAtIndex:0] class]*)[ArrayOfViews objectAtIndex:0] to replace (YourObjectType*)[ArrayOfViews objectAtIndex:i] should work no ?

Comment: :) Well that's an interesting thing to try out, but no, I think it results in a compiler error. The way I see it, if you know the method signature for the object, you should know the object type as well.

Comment: You're agree, it's not working :/ I could'nt just add the cast as you put in the first time, more than create a new object ? Because all objects in the Array are from differents objects type, and that's why i use an array :/

Comment: I agree that capturing a value of type `id` in a strongly typed variable is usually a good idea, but you should remove the cast in your example as it has no effect at all.

Comment: By the way, the compiler will allow you to call any method that's currently visible on an object of type `id`, so using a local variable doesn't address the OP's question.

Comment: jlehr, based on your comment and your answer, if OP forgot a #import statement, there would be a runtime error. The fact that the code runs despite the warning means that it's an issue with typing.

Comment: By the way, user2057209, unless all your custom objects inside the array respond to the same method signature, your code seems potentially unsafe. Even if they do respond, it might be a good idea to have a cleaner implementation in place.

Comment: @Sid Wrong. Runtime errors have nothing to do with type declarations, whether in header files or elsewhere. I agree with your other comment though, particular in light of the OP's subsequent clarification that the objects in the array are all of different types.

Comment: jlehr, I never said that runtime errors have anything to do with type declarations. I was telling the asker that the lack of a type declaration might be the reason for the warning. However, I do concede that a missing #import would most probably result in a compiler error and not in a runtime error. Though I've faced some situations where it results in a warning which leads to a runtime error (can't remember the exact scenario right now, and don't have access to my IDE to test it out at this moment). OP left out some details that left to a lot of speculation :) Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an `#import` statement for the header that declares the method or methods you want to call.

Comment: The asker mentions that the code works. There would be a runtime error if he forgot a #import statement.

Comment: @Sid Please explain how lack of a compile-time declaration can trigger a runtime error.

Comment: @user2057209 Saying that you have an `#import` statement is meaningless unless you identify the header file it refers to. And even that isn't terribly meaningful without examining the contents of the header. If the imported header doesn't contain a declaration of the method you're calling, you'll still get the same warning message.

Comment: I've import the header, and the method was declare into the header file, that was not the problem =)